# How to use title method in print function, if one of the value in dictionary is a 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python. I have a doubt.

```
pet_0 = {
    'owner_name' : 'john',
    'pet_animal' : 'dog',
    'pet_name' : 'ghost',
    'age' : 8,
    'diet' : 'mutton',
    }

pet_1 = {
    'owner_name' : 'arya',
    'pet_animal' : 'cat',
    'pet_name' : 'nymeria',
    'age' : 6,
    'diet' : 'chicken',
    }

pet_2= {
    'owner_name' : 'bran',
    'pet_animal' : 'crow',
    'pet_name' : 'summer',
    'age' : 2,
    'diet' : 'worms',
    }

pets = [pet_0, pet_1, pet_2]

for pet in pets:

    print(f"\nDetails about {pet['pet_name'].title()}:")

    for key, value in pet.items():
        print(f"\t{key}: {value}")
```

The above print function works perfectly, but when I use:

```
for key, value in pet.items():
    print(f"\t{key.title()}: {value.title()}")
```

There is an error because a value in the dictionary is a integer.
So how to use title method in print function, if one of the value in the dictionary is an int?

Comment: `str(value).title()`

Comment: seems to work for me. what's the error?

Comment: @AnthonySottile

Earlier I tried ```srt{value.title()}``` insted of ```{str(value).title()}```


Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
 print(f"\t{key.title()}: {value.title()}")
```

by:

```
 print(f"\t{key.title()}: {str(value).title()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`.title()` is a method on `str` instances and won't be present on other things:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x.title()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'title'
```

many things however can be *converted* into strings using the `str` builtin:

```
>>> y = str(x)
>>> y.title()
'5'
```

Note that for things which are already strings, calling `str` is a noop:

```
>>> z = 'foo'
>>> str(z) is z
True
```

combining this knowledge with your existing code, you'd print:

```py
for key, value in pet.items():
    print(f"\t{key.title()}: {str(value).title()}")
```